# How to add Animated Image In Cocos2D without use of TexturePacker?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocos2d-iphone

I am New at iOS Development.
I am also starting to learn Cocos2D.

I've read this tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/tutorials#cocos2d

It is a superb tutorial for beginners, but I'm also interested in animating the image. How can I accomplish animation?

So I read tutorial *(describe from Above Link)* about how to put animated image with simple Project.

In This tutorial I used `TexturePacker` and it's working... but I want to know more about how to animate images **without** using `TexturePacker`.

Is it possible? If so, then please explain how or link to tutorials on how to make it work.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think the reason why yo excluding texture packer is it's paid. Am i right? If yes, then you can use zwoptex to create spritesheet. And no, that you can loop trough the image and replace the image one by one with delay-finite delay(small), you will get animation.

Comment: @Rao27- thanks for replay, No its not real problem (TexturePacker is paid) but i want to add more knowledge for me.. is it possible or not ?? because in Cocoa-Touch, We use UIImageView and We can put Animation of Image by "animation" property of UIImageView. "animation" property of UIImageView take NAMutableArray of Images. so it is good and easy way for animation.. so i want to know that this kind of functionally available in Cocos2D (CCSprite) ???

Comment: Yes, it's possible.you can do animation. To do that, you have to make your own snippet to do animation. You can change the texture of sprite that means you can do animation.

Comment: @Rao27- you have any example of link of tutorial then please put here it as answer, it is very helpful for me :) thank :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run animation from file.

```
    CCSprite *coin = [CCSprite spriteWithFile:@"MyImage_1.png"];
    coin.position  = ccp(mS.width*0.5f, mS.height*0.5f);
    [self addChild:coin z:2];

    {
        NSString *animationName = @"UNIQUE_ANIMATION_NAME";

        CCAnimation* animation = nil;
        animation = [[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache]  animationByName:animationName];

        if(!animation)
        {
            NSMutableArray *animFrames = [NSMutableArray array];

            for( int i=1;i<=5;i++)
            {
                NSString* path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"MyImage_%d.png", i];
                CCTexture2D* tex = [[CCTextureCache sharedTextureCache] addImage:path];
                CGSize texSize = tex.contentSize;
                CGRect texRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, texSize.width, texSize.height);
                CCSpriteFrame* frame = [CCSpriteFrame frameWithTexture:tex rect:texRect];
                [animFrames addObject:frame];
            }

            animation = [CCAnimation animationWithSpriteFrames:animFrames];

            animation.delayPerUnit = 0.175f;
            animation.restoreOriginalFrame = YES;

            [[CCAnimationCache sharedAnimationCache] addAnimation:animation name:animationName];
        }

        if(animation)
        {
            CCAnimate *animAction  = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:animation];
            [coin runAction:animAction];
        }
    }
```

Comment: @guru- Really thanks dude its working for me..have a link of tutorial of this then please put link here .. thanks :)